# how to send data from component to route ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember js of version 2.10 And i am trying to send data from component to route.

Here is my component template

```
<div class="pull-right search-section">
    <form class="form-inline search-box" {{action save on="submit"}}>
      <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{input value=search class="form-control" placeholder="Search anything"}}
      </div>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="link-advance-search">Advance Search</a>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to send data to route from component js file with following code
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  save: function () {
        var search = this.get('search');
        console.log(this.sendAction('saveAction',search));
  }
});
```

And trying to get at route js file with following code

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({  
    actions: {
        saveAction: function(search_string){
            alert('fhdishf');
        }
    }
});
```

But unfortunately did not getting anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use closure actions and [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the action to the routes controller which then bubbles to the route if the controller does not define the action.

```
// Component in Template
{{task-item content=task tasksController=this}}

// Component Action
actions: {
    copyTask: function(){
        this.get('tasksController').send('your-action');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your template file,

```
{{task-item
  data=model
  innerActionName=outterActionName
}}
```

The ember way of doing things is **Data down, Action up**. To pass the data back to the controller/router, you have to make it call the upper action (from controller/router)

Inside your component JavaScript file,

```
actions: {
  componentActionName(param) {
    this.sendAction("innerActionName", param);
  }
}
```

`componentActionName` is what you need to put inside your template file which triggers the function defined inside component JS file.

Inside your component HBS file,

```
<div {{action "componentActionName" param}}>{{param}}</div>
```

`{{action "componentActionName" param}}`, is how you can pass the parameter back to component, and then controller/route.

**One more thing**

A component should be isolated, which means a simple component should not **aware** the surrounding environment. It **only** knows the data passed into it and can only perform data manipulation by passing the action and paramter to the right place (the route).